# How can I prevent users from logging in and then typing a url and carry the session to that url?

Tags: php, html, session

I am creating a website where you can login to a free version of a specific area, and you pay to get to a paid version of that specific area, but when I login into the free version of that area and if I type in the url of the paid version, it takes me there, how can I make sure that when the url is typed in it redirects the user.

The index.php for the free version is the same for the paid version.

Here is the code for the free version:

index.php:

```
<!--
//index.php
!--> 
<?php

include('database_connection.php');

session_start();

include('session.php'); 

if(!isset($_SESSION['id']))
{

}


?>  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <?php
            include('menu.php');
            ?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <br>
                        <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #fff1a3;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <h3 class="panel-title" style="color: white"><br></h3>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="image_upload">
                                        <form id="uploadImage" method="post" action="upload.php">
                                            <label for="uploadFile"><img src="image.png" /></label>
                                            <input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile" accept=".jpg, .png, .mp4" />
                                        </form>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <form method="post" id="post_form">

                                <div class="form-group" id="dynamic_field">

                                    <textarea style="resize: none;" name="post_content" id="post_content" maxlength="160" class="form-control" placeholder="Make a post"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div id="link_content"></div>
                                <div class="form-group" align="right">

                                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="insert" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" id="post_type" value="text" />
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="submit" style="float:left; background-color: #a5dbff; width: 12%; border: none; margin-left: -1.6%;" name="share_post" id="share_post" class="btn btn-primary" value="Post" />
                                </div>

                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">All Posts</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div id="post_list">

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <br>
                        <div class="panel-heading" style='background-color: #5bc0de;'>
                            <h3 class="panel-title"  style='color: white;'>Users</h3>
                        </div>

                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div id="user_list"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>

<?php

include('jquery.php');

?>
```

login for free version:

```
<!--
//login.php
!-->

<?php

include('database_connection.php');

session_start();

$message = '';

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
    header('location:index.php');
}

if(isset($_POST["login"]))
{
    $query = "
    SELECT * FROM tbl_twitter_user
        WHERE username = :username
    ";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(
        array(
            ':username' => $_POST["username"]
        )
    );
    $count = $statement->rowCount();
    if($count > 0)
    {
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            if(password_verify($_POST['password'], $row['password']))
            {
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
                $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
                header('location: page.php');
            }
            else
            {
                $message = '<label>Wrong Password</label>';
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $message = '<label>Wrong Username</labe>';
    }
}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>Connect Kitty</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="mdp.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
    </head>
    <body> 
     <br> 



   <script type="text/javascript">
   <!--
   var step=1
   function slideit(){
   document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")
   if(step<6)
   step++
   else
   step=1
   setTimeout("slideit()",2500)
   }
   slideit()
   </script>
        </div>
    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="container" style="text-align: center">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="regisFrm">

                <div class="panel panel-default" align="center">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form method="post">
                        <p class="text-danger"><?php echo $message; ?></p>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="email" class="form-control" required />
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="phone" class="form-control" required />
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" class="btn btn-info" value="Login" />
                        </div>
                        <br>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br><p id="u" align="center">Don't have an account? <a href="new.php">Register</a></p>
        <footer><br><br><a class='term' href='CK TermsofService.pdf'>Terms, Data Policy, and Cookies Policy</a><br><br><br></footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is the login for the paid version:

login.php:

```
<!--
//login.php
!-->

<?php

include('database_connection.php');

session_start();

$message = '';

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
 }

if(isset($_POST["login"]))
{
    $query = "
    SELECT * FROM tbl_twitter_user
        WHERE username = :username AND plan = 1
    ";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(
        array(
            ':username' => $_POST["username"]
        )
    );
    $count = $statement->rowCount();
    if($count > 0)
    {
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            if(password_verify($_POST['password'], $row['password']))
            {
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
                $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
                header('location: index.php');
            }
            else
            {
                $message = '<label>Wrong Password</label>';
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $message = '<label>You are not a subscriber, to become a subscriber, return <a href="../mop/paidcatwalk.php">here</a></label>';
    }

}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>Connect Kitty</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="mdp.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    </head>
    <body> 
   <script type="text/javascript">
   <!--
   var step=1
   function slideit(){
   document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")
   if(step<6)
   step++
   else
   step=1
   setTimeout("slideit()",2500)
   }
   slideit()
   </script>
        </div>
    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="container" style="text-align: center">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="regisFrm">

                <div class="panel panel-default" align="center">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form method="post">
                        <p class="text-danger"><?php echo $message; ?></p>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="email" class="form-control" required />
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="phone" class="form-control" required />
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" class="btn btn-info" value="Login" />
                        </div>
                        <br>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br><p id="u" align="center">Don't have an account? <a href="new.php">Register</a></p>
        <footer><br><br><a class='term' href='CK TermsofService.pdf'>Terms, Data Policy, and Cookies Policy</a><br><br><br></footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried using this:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['login'])) {
 header('Location: login.php');
} 
?>
```

Which would trigger a redirection if the actual login form was not submitted to enter the page, but when I use this line of code when I login it does not direct me to the index.php page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the *authorization* state in the session, not just the *authentication* state.

Comment: I do not understand, could you please clarify more?

Comment: Presumably you have some record of whom has paid (you did nor say if this was the case not how the data is stored). You need to retrieve this data and evaluate it before your code renders a restricted page. This is an authorization. Since you are already using sessions, it would be a good idea to retrieve the data at the time the user is authenticated and cache the user's authorizations in the session.

Comment: There is a column named plan in the database with the users, and when the user enters their email in the payment form and the payment goes through then the column plan changes from 0 to 1

Comment: @Social So read that value from the database when they login, and store it into your session. And in those places where you show paid content, you check that session value before you do so …